# Render and cache a heterogenous collection in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on an activity stream and have an Event model with subclasses for each type of event, such as StatusChanged etc.

Each type of event has a corresponding partial that formats the event for rendering.

Rails can render heterogenous collections in this manner, and its working out just fine until I try to cache the collection with the `cached: true` option on the render call.

Here's what I'm working on:

```
= render partial: events, as: :event, cached: true
```

where `events` is the heterogenous collection.

I've also overridden the `to_partial_path` on event so that partials can be stored in events/_event_type.html.haml vs events/event_type/_event_type.html.haml:

```
# Render partials from events/_<type> rather than default events/<type>/_<type>
  def to_partial_path
    self.class.name.underscore
  end
```

Here's the top of the stack trace for the issue I'm running into:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `virtual_path' for nil:NilClass:
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer/collection_caching.rb:35:in `expanded_cache_key'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer/collection_caching.rb:30:in `block in collection_by_cache_keys'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer/collection_caching.rb:29:in `collection_by_cache_keys'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer/collection_caching.rb:15:in `cache_collection_render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:326:in `block in render_collection'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:319:in `render_collection'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:308:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
  app/views/job_applications/_activity.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_job_applications__activity_html_haml__883799091596117587_70254600015120'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:343:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:311:in `block in render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
  app/views/job_applications/_edit.html.haml:29:in `_app_views_job_applications__edit_html_haml__4043825476406280496_70254604867100'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:343:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:311:in `block in render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:144:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
```

Digging into `lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer/collection_caching.rb:35` it looks like `@template` is `nil`.

Its also notable that this issue did not come up while the collection had only one type of Event in it. As soon as the collection contained two types of events...boom.

Has anyone run into this before? It might be as straightforward as "You can't cache a heterogenous collection in this way".